# How can I refactor C++ source code using emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs, refactoring

I'm interested mostly in C++ and method/class name/signature automatic changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do this a lot, so I'm axiously awaiting other replies too.

The only tricks I know are really basic. Here are my best friends in Emacs when refactoring code:

```
M-x query-replace
```

This allows you to do a global search and replace. You'll be doing this a ton when you move methods and commonly-accessed data to other classes or namespaces.

```
C-x 3
```

This gives you a display with two buffers side-by side. You can then proceed to load different files in them, and move your cursor from one to the other with `C-x o`. This is pretty basic stuff, but I mention it because of how powerful it makes the next one...

```
C-x (
(type any amount of stuff and/or emacs commands here)
C-x )
```

This is how you define a macro in emacs. Any time you find yourself needing to do the same thing over and over to a bunch of code (and it is too complex for query-replace), this is a lifesaver. If you mess up, you can hit `C-g` to stop the macro definition, and then undo (`C-_`) until you are back to where you started. The keys to invoke the macro are `C-x e`. If you want to do it a bunch of times, you can hit `Esc` and type in a number first. Eg: `Esc 100 C-x e` will try to invoke your macro 100 times.

(Note: On Windows you can get "Meta" by hitting the Esc key, or holding down Alt).

Comment: There are lots of other good tools as well.  See the answer mentioning CEDET.  Also, I frequently use TAGS and M-x tags-query-replace to rename all matches to a tags search, which can span source files.  See also M-x grep-find, which makes it easy to find all occurrances of a symbol to replace.

Comment: I've tried mucking with tags before. It seemed way more trouble than it was worth. Perhaps during a refactor it would be worth it though?

Comment: But this isn't refactoring. This is manually going through and editing your entire program.

Comment: @vy32 - I agree that this isn't exactly what the OQ seemed to be asking for. But if you know a way to refactor without editing your program, I'd really like to hear about it. There may be a Turing Award in it for you...

Comment: Refactoring is different than manually editing your program. Refactoring is telling the editor "wherever you see the variable FOO change it to BAR." That will change the variables FOO and not the method calls FOO.

Comment: @vy32 - "Refactoring" is something a person does to source code. Tools help of course, but no matter how much the tool helps, it is the person doing the refactoring, not the tool.

Answer (score 35):

In recent Emacs versions (24), Semantic is able to this.

0. Possibly activate semantic mode <kbd>M-x semantic-mode RET</kbd>.
1. Bring up the Symref buffer with <kbd>C-c , g</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> to open all references.
3. Rename with <kbd>R</kbd>.
4. Save all the edited buffers with <kbd>C-x s !</kbd>

Comment: I believe it is `C-c , g` instead of what you've got.

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires POSIX environment. Trying to use it on MS Windows 7 (without Cygwin or minGw installed) I get "semantic-symref-tool-grep: Searching for program: no such file or directory, sh" after running `C-c , g`

Comment: @JakubNarębski you may be intersted in downloading some [GnuWin32 packages](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).  These packages do not require the overhead of Cygwin or MinGW.  You can download individual tools, and put their bin directories on your path variable.  I have all of mine installed to C:\Dev\Gnu32

Comment: This was really cool, but it doesn't quite understand how C++ works; it appears to assume there can be at most one variable with a name in a method, whereas C++ allows declarations of variables e.g. in for loop initialisers.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks sharing this trick that is not easily discoverable.

Answer (score 26):

If you can program in elisp, you can look to combination of cedet + srecode from [CEDET libraries](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) - it provide all instruments for this task - find callers of functions, get signature, etc. But you need to create refactory tool yourself, using these instruments

Comment: Just looking at the CEDET page, this appears to be a much better answer than the one selected...

Comment: (Edited to add the CEDET page link). I'm not sure I disagree with Jared, but I'd have to try it. The "you need to create refactory tool yourself" bit looks kinda omnious though...

Answer (score 9):

The current (2022) state of the art is, I would say, using emacs [`lsp-mode`](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/) with a suitable language server.

With the [`clangd`](https://clangd.llvm.org/) or [`ccls`](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls), which provide the "language server protocol" (lsp) and connect to `lsp-mode`, you can refactor names with:

<kbd>M-x lsp-rename</kbd>

To simplify this setup, I'd recommend using [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) with `c-c++` and `lsp` layers (and using `clangd`).

Answer (score 8):

For somewhere in between refactoring tools and simple regex, since Emacs 22 you can embed arbitrary elisp expressions in your replacement text, which allows you to do incredibly powerful text manipulation.  Steve Yegge wrote a [good article](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/06/shiny-and-new-emacs-22.html) on this a while ago.

Comment: Wow. That totally rocks. I've been using emacs for so long, I never realised they added that.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't refactoring.

Answer (score 7):

A friend of mine was playing with [xrefactory](http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html) and said it worked pretty well. It isn't cheap though.

Comment: It's not gratis and it's not libre. :(

Comment: While this is quite true, the OP didn't ask for a free solution. :) That being said, xrefactory hasn't seen an update since 2007, so it might have trouble refactoring modern C++11 and its decendants.

Comment: There was a free version for C/Java and also a GPL:d version released in 2009. The GPL'd version still lives on at https://github.com/thoni56/c-xrefactory and is more complete than semantic-refactor. But it does not support C++, though.

Answer (score 4):

Build cscope symbols.

lookup the symbol you want to refactor.

get into the cscope window, and start a macro after placing cursor on first occurence

- ret
- c-f your symbol start
- navigate to start of your symbol
- modify the word
- c-x o (back to cscope)
- n (for next cscope symbol)

you have to just c-x c-e now

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree that find-and-replace work fine.  However , a really nice feature of cedet is 'semantic-symref-list'.

With the cursor on a method, run this command, and you will be presented with a buffer that lists all of the places in your code that reference this tag.

You can still use find-and-replace tricks, and this will confirm that you have changed all the references.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using *cquery* for my C++ completion which uses Microsoft LSP for IDE <-> Tool communication. *cquery* server satisfies the requests of the LSP protocol using a clang backend.

*lsp-emacs* is the package that sits between emacs and the *cquery* backend (cquery-emacs) which exposes an `lsp-rename` function. As a completion system, *cquery* has been very reliable and fast by the way, highly recommended.

Give it a try, follow the getting-started guide on the *cquery* github:
https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery/wiki/Emacs

Once you've got *cquery* setup:

1. Hover your cursor over an identifier (class, var, whatever) you'd like to rename.
2. M-x `lsp-rename`
3. Enter the **new** name for the identifier.
4. Do **C-x s** (save **some** buffers), which will prompt you to save
   all the buffers that were touched by the refactor.

You should probably go through all modified buffers and check what was done after refactoring with any tool/language.

Comment: Yeah, this is the modern way in 2018.